# Is $ f:]0, \pi[\times ]0,2\pi[\to \mathbb{R}^3 $ an immersion?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, jacobian

> I have the function $ f:]0, \pi[\times ]0,2\pi[\to \mathbb{R}^3 $ given by
> $$ f(x,y):=\begin{pmatrix}(R+r\cos(y))\cos(x)\\(R+r\cos(y))\sin(x)\\r\sin(y)\end{pmatrix} $$ and $ R>r>0 $ are fixed values. I want to examine if $ f $ is an immersion.
> If $ f $ is an immersion then $ f $ is continuos and differentiable and the derivative of $ f $ is injective.

At first I calcualted the jacobian matrix of $ f $ for all $ (x,y)\in ]0,\pi[\times ]0,2\pi[ $:

$$ Df(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}-(R+r\cos(y))\sin(x)&-r\sin(y)\cos(x)\\(R+r\cos(y))\cos(x)& -r\sin(y)\sin(x)\\0&r\cos(y)\end{pmatrix}. $$

I defined a new function with compoments of the derivative by $ g:]0, \pi[\times ]0,2 \pi[\to \mathbb{R}^5 $ with

$$g(x,y):=\begin{pmatrix}-(R+r\cos(y))\sin(x)\\(R+r\cos(y))\cos(x)\\-r\sin(y)\cos(x)\\-r\sin(y)\sin(x)\\r\cos(y)\end{pmatrix}.$$
I want to examine if $ f $ is injective. So I define a new function $ F:]0, \pi[^2\times ]0,2 \pi[^2 $ with

$$F(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2):=g(x_1,y_1)-g(x_2,y_2)=\begin{pmatrix}-(R+r\cos(y_1))\sin(x_1)+(R+r\cos(y_2))\sin(x_2)\\(R+r\cos(y_1))\cos(x_1)-(R+r\cos(y_2))\cos(x_2)\\-r\sin(y_1)\cos(x_1)+r\sin(y_2)\cos(x_2)\\-r\sin(y_1)\sin(x_1)+r\sin(y_2)\sin(x_2)\\r\cos(y_1)-r\cos(y_2)\end{pmatrix}$$
So I have to consider $ F(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=(0,0,0,0,0)^T $. But to be honest I have no idea where I should start to solve this huge system of equations.

Comment: I do not understand why you defined such a $g$. $d f$ is injective if the Jacobian matrix has full rank, so if its colums are linearly independent. And this can be checked with bare hands

Comment: If it is not clear yet, your $f$ defines a torus, the surface of revolution for a circle with radius $r$ whose center has distance $R$ to the $z$ axis. The $x$ and $y$ are the rotation angle around the $z$ axis, and the angle to describe the cross-section circle. It is then clear that $f$ is a global injection, although this can also be deduced algebraically from your system.

Comment: Yes I tried to algebraically calculate it but I gave it up because I was so confused about the special cases (like cos(.) =0 and so on...).